# In Identity Server 4, how to add actual users, not test users

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, identityserver4

I'm learning Identity Server 4 and it frustrates me that all examples given show how to add Test(Demo Sample) Users, through a middleware config 'AddTestUsers()'.

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

                // see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html
                options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
            })
                .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users)
```

**How does one actually add ones own users???**

I thought of asking the question here so that other newbies in the future can get their head around this. Adding Users (Username + Password) is one of the main reasons for using Identity Server!

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, if you want to use real information, you need to connect to your database.

#### Connect DB

The authorities provide a very detailed connection scheme. Here is connection solution.http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/5_entityframework.html

#### Custom User

In general, we prefer custom user attributes. You need to create a custom user that inherits from `IdentityUser`.

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    // every attr you want
    // ...
}
```

With the user, the DB context needs to be customized:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>, ...>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options){}
}
```

In `Startup.cs`, add DB context.

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseYourDbSystem(connectionString));
```

In fact, it is already successful. For testing purposes, you can add the UI.

#### Add UI

The UI was added for better testing. The full code is provided in the official UI, and you can run it with a few tweaks. You can run `dotnet new is4ui` in your project or create a new project. Here is UI solution. http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/2_interactive_aspnetcore.html

#### Modify the contents of the login page

At `Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs`, you can see that the `TestUser` is injected in the constructor. Delete it and inject the following:

```cs
UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager
```

Find `Login` post action, Modify the login validation logic.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model, string button)
{
    // some other code
    // ...
    
    // This login logic
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberLogin, true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // Here you can do a few things after a successful login
                // ...

                await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, user.Id.ToString(), user.UserName));
            }

            if (_interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(model.ReturnUrl) || Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
            }
            return Redirect("~/");
        }
    }
    // other code
}
```