# What is the right way for implement and authenticate Db Users in IS4 instead of Test Users?

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm working on microservices and implementing Hybrid flow. My project is working fine with Test Users.
But I need to make it more dynamic and authenticate my DB users instead of Test Users.

I'm sharing my authentication project startup.cs file code here, which I've tried yet:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
            .AddRoles<Role>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            })
            // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
    }
```

After running my above code I'm unable to login into my authentication server

[image]

No error is showing on the console window

[image]

Also same in the browser console

[image]

What if I run the below code is working fine and system log me in

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddTestUsers(Config.TestUsers)
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            })
            // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            });
    }
```

[image]

What I'm missing in the above code? what is the right way to authenticate the user from database instead of using Test Users?

Comment: Admin Skoruba Duende IdentityServer, it comes with login proyect with this implemented:
https://github.com/skoruba/Duende.IdentityServer.Admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found my question answer but it's strange that Identity Server 4 official docs not provided any documentation for switching Test Users to Actual User and tweaking at UI level.

Answer is:

**Modify the contents of the login page**

At `Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs`, you can see that the TestUser is injected in the constructor. Delete it and inject the following:

Replace below:

```
private readonly TestUserStore _users;
```

With this:

```
private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
```

in constructor, replace below:

```
IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction,
            IClientStore clientStore,
            IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider,
            IEventService events,
            TestUserStore users = null)
        {
            _users = users ?? new TestUserStore(TestUsers.Users);
            _interaction = interaction;
            _clientStore = clientStore;
            _schemeProvider = schemeProvider;
            _events = events;
        }
```

With this:

```
public AccountController(
            UserManager<User> userManager,
            SignInManager<User> signInManager,
            IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction,
            IClientStore clientStore,
            IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider,
            IEventService events)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _interaction = interaction;
            _clientStore = clientStore;
            _schemeProvider = schemeProvider;
            _events = events;
        }
```

Find Login post action, Modify the login validation logic.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberLogin, lockoutOnFailure: true);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
        await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, user.Id.ToString(), user.UserName));

        if (context != null)
        {
            if (await _clientStore.IsPkceClientAsync(context.Client.ClientId))
            {
                // if the client is PKCE then we assume it's native, so this change in how to
                // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
                return View("Redirect", new RedirectViewModel { RedirectUrl = model.ReturnUrl });
            }

            // we can trust model.ReturnUrl since GetAuthorizationContextAsync returned non-null
            return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
        }

        // request for a local page
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect("~/");
        }
        else
        {
            // user might have clicked on a malicious link - should be logged
            throw new Exception("invalid return URL");
        }
    }

    await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginFailureEvent(model.Username, "invalid credentials"));
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, AccountOptions.InvalidCredentialsErrorMessage);
}
```

At `Quickstart/Extensions.cs` append following code

```
public static async Task<bool> IsPkceClientAsync(this IClientStore store, string client_id)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(client_id))
    {
        var client = await store.FindEnabledClientByIdAsync(client_id);
        return client?.RequirePkce == true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Original Answer with old modifications:

[In Identity Server 4, how to add actual users, not test users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66648256/in-identity-server-4-how-to-add-actual-users-not-test-users)

Comment: I am also trying implement with actual user instead of test user & found your comment on udemy course.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: How mobile application will this identity server to login as I have both web and mobile application which can consume my protected api. Mobile application will send username/password for login.  Then can't use identity server login UI